# Issue with setting up Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have just set up a new Linux box and trying to install vagrant on it. The issue is that when I am running vagrant up command, I am getting the following error:

> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
>
> The directory Vagrant will use to store local environment-specific
> state is not accessible. The directory specified as the local data
> directory must be both readable and writable for the user that is
> running Vagrant.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I had the same issue in Windows and then I realized that my vagrant folder (Home) was "read only". I gave "Full Control" access to the folder and solved the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think a better way is to provide your user the required permission to the directory by making the user the owner - where you want the `vagrant` to be booted:

```
$ sudo chown -R <user> <directory>
```

and then you will be easily able to do:

```
$ vagrant up
```

Using `sudo` for `vagrant up` is unusual as why do you want to run your virtual machine as a root user.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and I solved it by run the terminal with"run as administrator". It's quite easy.
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue four years later and could not fix it using chmod or even @Ziya's comment under the initial question (which brought me closer to the resolution though).

In my case, I use Vagrant 2.2.6 on Windows 10, and use Cygwin as a command line interface.

For the error to disappear, I had to :

1. open Windows Explorer
2. right-click .vagrant folder in the location where I typed vagrant up
3. access the "Properties" menu
4. then, in the "Security" tab, update the authorizations for my user, granting total control

[Properties window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcyRp.jpg)

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow these steps:

1) install vagrant 1.7.1 
2) install virtual box 4.1, 4.2, or 4.3
3) use the administrator name in the custom directory (e.g., for windows users c:\users\AdminName\myvagrant or for Mac/Linux users /home/Admin/myvagrant)

For instance: `c:\users\safwan\myvagrant` where safwan is the user with administrator rights/privileges.

Copy the file name Vagrantfile in the myvagrant forlder.

4) Now open DOS window as shown in the  picture and follow the steps in the DOS window changing the admin name

[image]